# Changing the ColorMatrix without having to create a new ColorMatrixColorFilter each time

Tags: java, android, bitmap

This is for a game I'm making for Android, and what I'm trying to do is each time I draw these certain bitmaps, I want the colours to be changed by x amount to appear more red in contrast with a certain value. I've so far manage to do it like this:

```
public void drawObstacle(Pixmap pixmap, int x, int y, float red){
    mColorMatrix.setScale(1 + (0.0015833f * red), 1 - (0.004566f * red), 1 - (0.004566f * red), 1);
    mObstaclePaint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(mColorMatrix));
    mCanvas.drawBitmap(pixmap.getBitmap(), x, y, mObstaclePaint);
}
```

with perfect results.

However because of the nature of games, the method is being called so many times which causes it to lag noticeably and I speculated that the cause was the creation of new objects created each time which I proved by excluding it in my code. I feel that this lag is caused by the GC.

I've looked through the API/source code and found that the ColorMatrix is copied through to the ColorMatrixColorFilter's constructor, so I can't change it once it has been instantiated, and there doesn't seem to be any viable methods of changing it in any way.

My question is how I can create the same effect without making it lag/creating dozens of new objects each time?

Comment: cannot you cache `ColorMatrixColorFilter`s ?

Comment: I have done that already, but I still need to create a new object each time. There's no viable method of changing the contents of ColorMatrixColorFilter, once I've passed the ColorMatrix object into the constructor it copies the contents into a private variable which I can't access easily. So I have to create a new object each time.

Comment: You always have the dirty possibility to hack the object with inspection but if the attribute is so good encapsulate it is certainly for a good reason. I would prefer a more sophisticate analysis of the performances with the android profiler to be certain that the real bottleneck is not elsewhere.  https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-allocation.html